# FitBounds Yandex map, выборочных объектов по координатам

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как сделать Fitbounds нескольких объектов на карте yandex map по координатам

Пример google maps

```
const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
               this.markers.forEach((value) => {
                   bounds.extend(value.getPosition());
               });
               this.map.fitBounds(bounds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен [`util.bounds.fromPoints`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/util.bounds-docpage/#method_detail__fromPoints) и [`Map.setBounds`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#method_detail__setBounds).